# With functionaljava HList, is there a way to pass each element of an arbitrary HList to a corresponding curried function?

Tags: java, functional-programming, hlist

For example, if i had an HList:

`HList<A,HList<B,HList<C,HNil>>> list = ...`

Is there a way to apply each element to a curried function:

`F<A,F<B,F<C,D>>> f = ...`

in such a way that i would somehow get a `D`?

And furthermore, if i cons an `E` to the HList

`HList<E,HList<A,HList<B,HList<C,HNil>>>> list2 = list.extend((E)e);`

and then somehow apply

`F<E,F<A,F<B,F<C,D>>>> ef = ..`

to that HList in the same manner?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, `HList<A, HList <B,HList<C, HNil>>>` is incorrect. It must be `HCons<A, HCons<B, HCons<C, HNil>>>`.

> Is there a way to apply each element to a curried function:
>
> `F<A,F<B,F<C,D>>> f = ...`
>
> in such a way that i would somehow get a `D`?

If I understood your question, you want this:

```
A a = list.head();
B b = list.tail().head();
C c = list.tail().tail().head();
D d = f.f(a).f(b).f(c);
```

Does it answer your question, or did you mean something else?

> And furthermore, if i cons an `E` to the HList
>
> `HList<E,HList<A,HList<B,HList<C,HNil>>>> list2 = list.extend((E)e);`
>
> and then somehow apply
>
> `F<E,F<A,F<B,F<C,D>>>> ef = ..`
>
> to that HList in the same manner?

Again, if my understanding is correct:

```
E e = list2.head();
A a = list2.tail().head();
B b = list2.tail().tail().head();
C c = list2.tail().tail().tail().head();
D d = ef.f(e).f(a).f(b).f(c);
```

Comment: When i read my question three years later i see that its horrible. I thought of something along apply(f,list), and then later (using the same apply function) apply(ef,list2)